# Excluding rows in Query

Tags: mysql

I have data going back 15 years in my database and I would like to take the average of all the past years and comparing it with the data for the current year. 
I have a year column and I'm having trouble taking the average of the data while excluding the current year and then displaying the current year separately.

EDIT: This is what I have table[year, number] and I'm trying to achieve something like [average number(all years except current), number(current year) ]

Comment: Can you show the query you already tried?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the requirement here. Could you share your table's structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just having trouble creating a table-like structure in my question but I hope this is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you question lacks a lot of information, I can't build you a working query without seeing the actual table structure, but you can adjust it your self to the actual table/column names :

```
SELECT t.YourComparingColumn as this_year,s.last_year
FROM YourTable t
CROSS JOIN(SELECT AVG(t1.YourComparingColumn) as last_year FROM YourTable t1
           WHERE t1.year < year(now())) s
WHERE t.year = year(now())
```

If you want them grouped by any `ID` or something:

```
SELECT t.id,t.YourComparingColumn as this_year,s.last_year
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN(SELECT t1.id,AVG(t1.YourComparingColumn) as last_year FROM YourTable t1
           WHERE t1.year < year(now())
           GROUP BY t1.id) s
 ON(t.id = s.id)
WHERE t.year = year(now())
```

If you have more then 1 row for each year, you should also sum them.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information, I just couldn't create a table-like structure in my question, can you please check the edit and see if it makes more sense? Year is my primary key and I have it going from 2001 till 2016 and I want to display the average of 2001-2015 next to the data from 2016

Comment: This is what my query does, adjust it to your structure, make so efforts .